# How do I continue the game in Assassin's Creed 1 after I reach the credits?

Tags: assassins-creed

How do I continue playing Assassin's Creed 1 in my savegame (Wandering around, trying the air assassination skill, open-roaming, getting all the Templar flags, ...) after I reach the credits in the same savegame?

After going to the credits, I go back to the animus and I'm presented with the memories section. There's no option to continue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no continue option in the Animus since the story itself is over. You just jump back to a location in the memories section and continue finding flags, etc.

The best place to jump to is Memory Block 6, since from there you will have access to all areas of the map. You could also jump directly into an earlier memory and you will still have all your unlocked abilities and gear, but parts of the map will be locked.

Comment: Yes - I understand that you can jump back to a memory, but if I jump back to one of the previous memories, don't I lose the weapons and stats (Flags collected, etc.) that I collected in the later memories?

Comment: Nope, the collection stuff is 'global'. Once found they are always found. You will want to jump back to the latest memory that you can roam the entire world (except for Rome).

Comment: yup, @Tergiver is right. I was trying to find a picture of the memory menu, but couldn't

Comment: @Tergiver Alright, that's fine. ... Not sure what you mean by that you cannot roam the entire world (Except for Rome), because I don't think AC1 *has* Rome. ... I thought it was based in the Holy Land, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of AC2 which has Rome, but the mechanic is the same in both games. AC2 is a much better game, so hurry up and finish 1 =)

Answer (score 0):

go and read the girls emails on the animus computer and start unraveling the story using door codes and eagle vision to see the blood marks on the floors.

Comment: Does that even work?